# Find IList<object> specific object in List<IList<object>> using linq c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-5

C# code

```
var brightEdgeKeywordGroupRequest = new BrightEdgeRequest{
                    Dataset = "keywordgroup",
                    DimensionOptions = new BrightEdgeDimensionOptions
                    {
                        Time = brightEdgeOption.Equals(BrightEdgeOperations.KeywordGroupsWeekly) ? "weekly" : "monthly"
                    },
                    Filters = new List<IList<object>>
                    {
                        new List<object> {"time", "eq", request.StartTime.Year + (brightEdgeOption.Equals(BrightEdgeOperations.KeywordGroupsWeekly) ? GetWeekOfYear(request.StartTime): request.StartTime.Month.ToString("00")) },
                        new List<object> {"keywordgroup:id", "ne", "-1"},
                        new List<object> { "search_engine", new int[,] { { 1, 34 }, { 1, 36 }, { 2, 34 }, { 2, 36 }, { 3, 34 }, { 3, 36 } } }
                    }
                };
```

Want to get only **search_engine** from `brightEdgeKeywordGroupRequest.Filters`  but not getting the exact way. If some one have any solution so please share with us.

Comment: Down vote but why please give me reason??

Comment: `var se = (int[,])brightEdgeKeywordGroupRequest.Filters[2][1]`?

Comment: @FCin That will not return **search_engine** ;o)

Comment: @SirRufo Doesn't OP want collection? Or just the name?

Comment: @FCin Who knows? The question is unclear

Comment: @FCin Yes I want to get collection. You are right

Comment: @GovindaRajbhar Then edit your question and put some more information to it. What have you tried (code), what do you expect to get

Answer (score 0):

One possible way...

```
 var searchEngine = brightEdgeKeywordGroupRequest?
                    .Filters?
                    .FirstOrDefault(f => f.FirstOrDefault() is string && string.Equals((string)f.FirstOrDefault(), "search_engine", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))?
                    .ToArray()[1];
```

This returns the search_engine array portion, which is what I understood to be your goal.

`new int[,] { { 1, 34 }, { 1, 36 }, { 2, 34 }, { 2, 36 }, { 3, 34 }, { 3, 36 } }`

Comment: That seems like excessive null checking. Couldn't you use C# pattern matching like `f[0] is string fd && String.Equals(fd` ?